# jquery validation when field in DIV with display:none

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I got problem on fields with display:none ... 
I need that after click on submit form button the error message will appear even if the field to validate is in div with display:none setting. 
I find solution and try to add to the jQuery code setting

```
ignore: []
```

but this not change anything. Look at the div with class named 'moreurlinput', he got inline style display:none, but if you change this to display:inline (block,table etc.) the error of validation appear.

html

```
<form id="post" action="http://m.onet.pl" method="post" class="validatedForm">
<div class="moreurlinput" style="display:none">
    <input class="moreurl center" type="text" name="moreurl" id="moreurl" />
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit" />Add</button>
</div>
</form>
```

jquery

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
errorElement: "div",
errorClass: 'validate-error',
rules: {
    "moreurl": {
        required: true
    }
},
messages: {
    moreurl: "Please define 'More' URL value"
}
```

});

**HERE**: http://jsfiddle.net/Lprn89o8/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validation is working exactly as expected. Your whole problem is that the error element is also *inside* of your hidden `div` so the message cannot be seen.

The solution is to use the `errorPlacement` option to place the message *outside* of your hidden `div`.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
},
```

You also need the `ignore: []` option so that nothing is ignored and your hidden element is validated.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lprn89o8/4/**

---

An alternative solution would simply move `display:none` to the `input` element, allowing the `div` to remain visible.

**Alternative:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lprn89o8/5/**

---

**EDIT**:

The HTML for your `button` element is invalid.  You should not use a "self-closing" tag since the `<button>` element itself is a *container* that has a closing tag.

```
<button type="submit" />Add</button>
```

should be...

```
<button type="submit">Add</button>
```