# Contact Form 7 Ignore validation when field in DIV with display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have a problem with validation after submitting the form when field in DIV with display:none.
I am using jquery to show/hide DIV for radio buttons.
And all the field should be mandatory fields..

Is there possible to ignore validation, when field in DIV with display:none in contact form7.

Please help me to find a solution

Code for reference.

```
<div class="f7-row">
    <div class="f7-label">Sorgeberechtigte*</div>
    <div class="f7-input">[radio Sorgeberechtigte "Mutter" "Vater" "beide" "andere Person"] </div>
</div>
<div id="mutter" style='display:none'>
    <h1>MUTTER</h1>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Vorname*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* MUTTER_Vorname]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Nachname*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* MUTTER_Nachname]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Straße*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* MUTTER_Strae]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">PLZ/Ort*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* MUTTER_PLZ]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Telefonnummer*</div><div class="f7-input">[tel* MUTTER_Telefonnummer]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">berufstätig ab Aufnahme- bzw. Betreuungszeitpunkt des Kindes?*</div><div class="f7-input">[radio MUTTER_Betreuungszeitpunkt "Ja" "Nein"]</div></div>
</div>
<div id="vater" style='display:none'>
    <h1>VATER</h1>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Vorname*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* VATER_Vorname]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Nachname*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* VATER_Nachname]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Straße*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* VATER_Strae]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">PLZ/Ort*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* VATER_PLZ]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Telefonnummer*</div><div class="f7-input">[tel* VATER_Telefonnummer]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">berufstätig ab Aufnahme- bzw. Betreuungszeitpunkt des Kindes?*</div><div class="f7-input">[radio VATER_Betreuungszeitpunkt "Ja" "Nein"]</div></div>
</div>
<div id="anderer" style='display:none'>
    <h1>anderer Personensorgeberechtigter</h1>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Vorname*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* anderer_Vorname]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Nachname*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* anderer_Nachname]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Straße*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* anderer_Strae]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">PLZ/Ort*</div><div class="f7-input">[text* anderer_PLZ]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">Telefonnummer*</div><div class="f7-input">[tel* anderer_Telefonnummer]</div></div>
    <div class="f7-row"><div class="f7-label">berufstätig ab Aufnahme- bzw. Betreuungszeitpunkt des Kindes?*</div><div class="f7-input">[radio anderer_Betreuungszeitpunkt "Ja" "Nein"]</div></div>
</div>
```

Js Code for reference

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.Sorgeberechtigte input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr('value') == 'Mutter') {
        $('#mutter').show(500);           
   }
   else {
        $('#mutter').hide(500);   
   }});
$('.Sorgeberechtigte input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr('value') == 'Vater') {
        $('#vater').show(500);           
   }
   else {
        $('#vater').hide(500);   
   }});
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871518/jquery-validation-when-field-in-div-with-displaynone?rq=1

Comment: Hai anam, I tired it but this is not working.. Actually this is wordpress plugin (Contact Form 7) And thanks for the reply